# Why are the leaves on my mango seedling turning brown?

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, diseases, mango

Also the tiny new leaves (on the top of the plant) are falling off right after they pop up. Then the plant grows new ones and they fall off again. Is it because of overwatering? I also recently had a lot of sciaras flying around, but I sprayed the plant and soil with tobacco and now there are almost none.
Thanks for the answer.

[image]